Where can I get english translation of Harita Smriti?
I searched a lot over the Internet but could not find any complete english translation of Harita smriti..Can someone guide as to where I can buy an english translation? Thanks

You can buy Harita Smriti/Samhita translated into English by Manmatha Nath Dutta from here: https://www.flipkart.com/harita-samhita/p/itmfys949gdrhcvj
This book https://ia803400.us.archive.org/10/items/samhitaoriginalt00duttuoft/samhitaoriginalt00duttuoft.pdf also has Harita Smriti translated by the same author. The book has translations of various other Smitis too.


Sir Not samhita smriti

Manu Smriti is often called Manu Samhita .. they are the same text .. similarly for Harita Smriti @Harsh
